# Calculate the value of the derivative of several parameters

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, derivative

I want to start sensitivity analysis by Hazen-Williams equation.

After defining variables and derivatives, I do not know how to apply a numeric value to each derived component.

I want to paste the value of each variable after derivation to get the final answer. How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
%%
% S=dO/dP      S:Absolute Sensivity;
% Sr=(dO/dP)*(P/O)     Sr:Relative Sensivity;
syms L Q C D Y;

Hf = 10.654*(Y)*L*(Q^1.852)*(C^-1.852)*(D^-4.87);
So = zeros(4,2);

dy=diff(Hf,Y);
dQ=diff(Hf,Q);
dC=diff(Hf,C);
dD=diff(Hf,D);
```

Comment: Did you look at [`subs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html)?

Comment: @cris-luengo I'm a beginner

Comment: How is that relevant? Does that mean you can’t read the documentation I linked? Sorry, I just don’t understand your reply.

Comment: @cris-luengo I read the subs that you linked but i can't  generalize it to polynomials

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found how to do this.

```
tic
clc;
clear;
close all;
%%
y=input('input λ: ');
l=input('input Lenght(m): ') ;
q=input('input Q(discharge): ') ;
c=input('input C(Heizen-wiliamz): ') ;
d=input('input Diameter(m): ') ;

% S=dO/dP      S:Absolute Sensivity;
% Sr=(dO/dP)*(P/O)     Sr:Relative Sensivity;
syms L Q C D Y;

Hf = 10.654*(Y)*L*(Q^1.852)*(C^-1.852)*(D^-4.87);
O=double(subs(Hf,{Y,L,Q,C,D},{y,l,q,c,d}));
So = zeros(4,2);

dy=diff(Hf,Y);
dQ=diff(Hf,Q);
dC=diff(Hf,C);
dD=diff(Hf,D);
dL=diff(Hf,L);

SA=zeros(5,2);
SA(1,1)=double(subs(dy,{Y,L,Q,C,D},{y,l,q,c,d}));
SA(1,2)=SA(1,1)*y/O;
SA(2,1)=double(subs(dQ,{L,Q,Y,C,D},{l,q,y,c,d}));
SA(2,2)=SA(2,1)*q/O;
SA(3,1)=double(subs(dC,{L,Q,Y,C,D},{l,q,y,c,d}));
SA(3,2)=SA(3,1)*c/O
SA(4,1)=double(subs(dD,{L,Q,Y,C,D},{l,q,y,c,d}));
SA(4,2)=SA(4,1)*d/O
SA(5,1)=double(subs(dL,{L,Q,Y,C,D},{l,q,y,c,d}));
SA(5,2)=SA(5,1)*l/O
clc;
```